# How to uninstall Python indent plug-in from Notepad++?

Tags: python, plugins, notepad++

I currently installed via plug-in manager of Notepad++ the Python Indent plug-in
I cannot uninstall it.

It's in update pane of Notepad++ plug-in manager, I check it and update it.
After update installation it is there again and not in installed plug-ins.
So it cannot be uninstalled.

Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found was to delete the dll of the plugin 
**"Python Indent.dll"** (and Python Indent directory if it exists)
 from the Notepad++ plugin directory, tipically:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins
```

Once I deleted the dll and restarted Notepad++ the Python Indent plug-in was gone

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had also this problem of a plugin crashing my notepad++ every minute, but I used notepad++ portable, instead, you just go to the directory where it's installed and look for the plugins directory, notepad++ should offer an inner functionality of doing this.